# NERDTree go to a directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm familiar with the `C` command to `cd` into a visible directory. What if I just want to go into a random directory and set that as the `cd`, something like:

```
C ~/.ssh
```

How would I do that in NERDTree?

Comment: There seems to be no such option available in the documentation. Pretty sad actually, seems like a feature worth having in any file explorer.